# cvMatchShapes function returns strange results

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I compare two similar shapes with help of cvMatchShapes() function.

```
  result  =  CvInvoke.cvMatchShapes(shapeA, shapeB, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CONTOURS_MATCH_TYPE.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3, 0);
```

But I get the result relatively large, 2.3 .

When I compare two **same** shapes:

```
result  =  CvInvoke.cvMatchShapes(shapeA, shapeB, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CONTOURS_MATCH_TYPE.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I3, 0);
```

I get result 1.25. (as I understand in this case I have to get result ~0)

Any idea why function returns such unexpected results?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are your shapeA and shapeB grayscale? have you tried running canny on it before match shapes? also have you tried the other CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1 or CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I2 types?

Comment: Yes,Mikos i tryed all the things above.

Comment: Are the sizes of shapes A and B are the same? If not there will be values different than 0.

Comment: As I understand there is no need to make normalization between to shapes.From documentation the compared shapes dosent have to be the same size.Do I missing somthing?